# Extract attendee response from google calendar event with python

Tags: python, calendar, zapier

This is a follow on question to one answered recently by wpercy and Kieran.
I'm trying to fashion some Python code to improve a Zap in Zapier.
The first stage involved extracting the attendee emails from the supplied (by Google) string variable containing the emails separated by commas.

What I now need to figure out is how to also extract the attendee responses and pair them or somehow get them to follow their corresponding attendee email address as the remaining steps in the Zap are carried out, once for each email/attendee.

Here is the solution code I have successfully tested. It deals with just the emails:

```
emails = []
attendeeList = input_data['attendeeEmails'].split(',')
for email in attendeeList:
    a = {'Email' : email.strip()}
    emails.append(a)
return emails
```

Here is the other solution offered by Kieran:

```
[{'Email': email.strip()} for email in input_data['attendeeEmails'].split(',')]
```

The Google Calendar data looks like this:

```
attendees:
    1:
        displayName:    Doug Christensen
        email:  xxxx@gmail.com
        responseStatus: needsAction
    2:
        displayName:    Doug Christensen
        email:  yyyyyy@gmail.com
        responseStatus: needsAction
    3:
        self:   true
        email:  zzzz@xyzmadscience.com
        organizer:  true
        responseStatus: accepted
```

So I want to get "responseStatus" and the only thing I could think to do was the following:

```
emails = []
position = 0
responseList = input_data['attendeeReponses'].split(',')
attendeeList = input_data['attendeeEmails'].split(',')
for email in attendeeList:
    a = {'Email' : email.strip(), 'responseStatus' :       reponseStatus(position).strip()}
    a = {'Email' : email.strip()}
    emails.append(a)
    position += 1
return emails
```

...but that does not work (says "error" in Zapier).

I'm pretty confused by the fact that the attendee emails are available in 2 Google variables "Attendee Emails" and "Attendees Email". One actually shows up in the variables to pass to the Zap's Python code as 'Attendees[]Email' while the other shows as 'Attendee Emails'. For the attendee responses there is only one option which manifests as 'Attendees[]ResponseStatus'.

I'm clearly no expert but these labels suggest to me a bit of a data structure? when the '[]' is included, making me think that an even more elegant method of extraction of the email and pairing with the attendee response, is possible.

I want the Python code to return the email and its corresponding attendee response in a way such that the following Zap steps will be performed once for each email/response pair.

Again, any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Doug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for your error is that you're trying to access an element in the list with parentheses `()`. You should be using brackets `[]`.

Even after fixing that, you can be doing this in a far more pythonic fashion. Instead of keeping track of your position in the list with its own variable, you should use the built-in function [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate). This will keep track of the index for you, and you won't have to increment it manually.

You would use it like this

```
emails = []

responseList = input_data['attendeeReponses'].split(',')
attendeeList = input_data['attendeeEmails'].split(',')
for i,email in enumerate(attendeeList):
    a = {'Email': email.strip(), 'responseStatus': reponseStatus[i].strip()}
    emails.append(a)
return emails
```

Comment: Thank you sooh much! I corrected some of my spelling (of "response") and made 1 tweak changing "responseStatus[]" to "responseList[]", and it worked great!